# How to prove that trace$(ABA^{-1}B^{-1})$=$3$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A,B$ are two $3 \times 3$ square matrices and trace(A) is defined as the sum of all diagonal elements. trace$(ABA^{-1}B^{-1})$=$3$

I could easily verify the above for the identity matrix.But I couldn't generalise it.

Please help me in this regard.thanks.

Comment: Are they 3x3 square matrices? Because if not, this is wrong. If $A$ and $B$ are the $n$ x $n$ identity matrices, then the trace of that is $n$, not 3.

Comment: Yes they are $ 3 \ times 3$ square matrix.

Comment: You can also verify it if $A$ and $B$ are commutative matrices!

Comment: Or if $AB$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Counterexample:
$$\begin{align}
A&=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
&B&=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\1&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\\A^{-1}&=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
&B^{-1}&=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0\\-1&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}$$
results in
$$ABA^{-1}B^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}3&-1&0\\1&0&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
with trace $4$.

Comment: Thanks a lot.it was a misprint in the question paper.however in the examination hall I checked for identity matrix got trace as 3.the answer key also gives the answer as trace to be 3.it make me feel that the question should have been regarding trace($ABCA^{-1}B^{-1}C^{-1})$=3 because earlier the question talked about three matrices A,B,C but ended up at just two.is the above always true then?.thanks.

Comment: @navinstudent: With the same $A,B$ as used in the counterexample, set $C$ to the identity, and you have a counterexample for the version with $C$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us see that $tr(AB) = tr(BA)$, when $A,B$ are square matrices of the same order (not so sure about other matrices although I think this holds true even then)

Now simply rearranging $tr(ABA^{-1}B^{-1}) = tr(I_{n}) = n$

Since in your question $n=3$, we are done.

Comment: It is contradictory.I have no objection to your answer.But what about the counterexample  by @ccorn.thanks.

Comment: I think I see it now....

Comment: I can't seem to edit my previous comment coz of being a new user, in any case, my point being that we cannot really rearrange $ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$ to $I_n$, which I stated just like that, silly of me.

Comment: Oh yes I also missed out that.had it been $tr(ABB^{-1}A^{-1}) we could simplify it to tr(I_{n}) = n$